# Excel: Combine multiple matrices into single matrix

Tags: excel, matrix

I'm organizing an Excel sheet containing various matrix calculations.
In order to obtain elegant code, I would need to glue two matrices of dimension n by 1 (n a natural number), based on previous data, together into an 2n by 1 matrix and use this new matrix inside a formula.

I wish to visualize neither the n by 1 nor the 2n by 1 matrices, as their existence is only required inside my calculations and serves no intuitional purpose.

I wish to fabricate a solution using only existing Excel-functions, within Office 365 (version 1902).

Conceptually, I would like to use column F, the result of E1:E5 below D1:D5 in a subsequent formula, where D and E are i.e. COS(A1:A5 *C1) and SIN(A1:A5 *C1)

```
     A     B     C     D     E     F
1  28,98        4392  0,66  0,75  0,66
2  30,00             -0,03  1,00 -0,03
3  29,99             -0,76 -0,65 -0,76
4  28,43              0,51 -0,86  0,51
5  15,04             -0,31  0,95 -0,31
6                                 0,75
7                                 1,00
8                                -0,65
9                                -0,86
10                                0,95
```

Note: The numbers serve merely as an illustration.

PS: Forgive me my inexperience in formulating questions. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're asking. Is it how to put the E1:E5 underneath D1:D5 in F1:F10?

Comment: Yes, but instead of having column F1:F10 in my excel sheet, I only need it as a factor in a matrix multiplication, so I do not wish to have cells containing those values.

Comment: What do you want to do with those values?

Comment: I want to multiply column F with another n by n matrix (above n =10), and use the result of that multiplication in another formula

Comment: Not sure you can do that with a formula without an intermediate stage (which doesn't mean it's not possible). Anyway you would need a 1x10 array.

Comment: The impossibility of such a solution is of course a possible answer to my question, although naturally not the one I'm hoping for. 
This part is just a piece of a puzzle where I'm pushing the limits of Excel regarding flexibility, so I wouldn't be surprised if this were to be such a limit.

Comment: Can't guarantee it's impossible, some formula whizz might be able to do it, but I don't know how.